# Can't reclaim lvm "thin pool" space

Tags: lvm

The pool usage is very large compared to the lvm volume, but it doesn't seem to be actually used.

Previously, the metadata area was full and the metadata was expanded. Since then I've had "lvm transaction id mismatch" issue and I solved it through vgcfgbackup -> change transaction id -> vgcfgrestore .

The unreclaimed lvm thin pool space problem occurred after vgcfgrestore.
deleting snapshots, fstrim for mounted lvm volumes didn't solve it either.
Any ideas for solving this problem?

```
# dmsetup ls | grep vg0 | sort -k2 -V
vg0-tpool0_tmeta    (253:4)
vg0-tpool0_tdata    (253:5)
vg0-tpool0-tpool    (253:6)
vg0-tpool0          (253:7)
vg0-tvol0           (253:8)
vg0-20221102.000001 (253:16)
vg0-20221102.060001 (253:17)
vg0-20221102.120001 (253:18)
vg0-20221101.120002 (253:19)
vg0-20221101.180001 (253:20)

# grep . /sys/block/dm-{4..8}/queue/discard_max_bytes 
/sys/block/dm-4/queue/discard_max_bytes:0
/sys/block/dm-5/queue/discard_max_bytes:0
/sys/block/dm-6/queue/discard_max_bytes:0
/sys/block/dm-7/queue/discard_max_bytes:0
/sys/block/dm-8/queue/discard_max_bytes:17179869184

# lvs -a vg0 -o +discards
  LV                 VG      Attr       LSize   Pool       Origin    Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Discards
  20221101.120002    vg0 Vwi-aotz-k  15.00t tpool0 tvol0 29.13                                               passdown
  20221101.180001    vg0 Vwi-aotz-k  15.00t tpool0 tvol0 29.13                                               passdown
  20221102.000001    vg0 Vwi-aotz-k  15.00t tpool0 tvol0 29.13                                               passdown
  20221102.060001    vg0 Vwi-aotz-k  15.00t tpool0 tvol0 29.13                                               passdown
  20221102.120001    vg0 Vwi-aotz-k  15.00t tpool0 tvol0 29.13                                               passdown
  tpool0             vg0 twi-aotz--  16.00t                          90.86  0.59                             passdown
  [tpool0_tdata]     vg0 Twi-ao----  16.00t                                                                      
  [tpool0_tmeta]     vg0 ewi-ao---- <15.01g                                                                      
  [tpool0_tmeta]     vg0 ewi-ao---- <15.01g                                                                      
  tvol0              vg0 Vwi-aotz--  15.00t tpool0                   29.13                                   passdown
  [lvol0_pmspare]    vg0 ewi------- <15.01g                                                                      
  [lvol0_pmspare]    vg0 ewi------- <15.01g                                                                      
  [lvol0_pmspare]    vg0 ewi------- <15.01g
```

Answer (score 0):

On my linux box this problem is solved. The cause was unknown, but I found a transaction id mismatch between the vgcfg and the thin_dump and solved it by matching transaction id.

I hope this helps someone.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74554604/14254717